# Speed Fan Software not detecting Fans

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan

2 weeks ago I built a PC with new configurations, but today I decided to change the fan speed for my pc case. I have 4 fans on my casing, 3 on the front and 1 at the back. If I am not wrong the front three fans are called `aux fans` and back one is called `system fan`. So to change the speed I downloaded the `Speed Fan` software and on the reading menu I can see its only showing the RPM of the `CPU` fan and not the other 4 fans, it's basically showing `0 RPM` for those. I am not sure why this is happening `Note: It is showing me the speed of my CPU fan and with the help of the software I can change the speed of it too`. Can anyone please tell me why it's not showing or what I need to do so that it shows over there?

Comment: Did you try going into BIOS or UEFI settings to try and change these settings? [UEFI or BIOS](https://itsfoss.com/check-uefi-or-bios/) it is usually not recommended to use a third party app to change these settings. also could you specify the processor model, and motherboard company ?

Comment: @EsvinJoshua I did went to BIOS and UEFI from here I can change the mode only looks like not able to change the speed/temperature also my processor is `AMD Ryzen 5 3400G Processor with Radeon RX Vega 11 Graphics`  and My motherboard is `AS Rock B450M Pro4-F`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpeedFan has limited chipset support. There's a support page with the supported chipsets listed here http://www.almico.com/forumindex.php

It's likely yours isn't on the list. If your chipset isn't there, all you can really do is appeal to the authors of the application to add support for your chipset in a later version.

Comment: How do I find what CHIP Set I have for my Mother Board ? My motherboard name is `AS Rock B450M Pro4-F`  I went to Device manager to find the Chip Set but I cant find any here ? Do I need to install any drivers if so what driver I should install ?

Comment: https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B450M%20Pro4-F/#Specification says "- AMD Promontory B450"

Comment: So this CHIP Set is not added on the Fan Speed software right ?

Comment: It would appear that that is a valid conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a summarised answer:

Sometimes SpeedFan doesn’t detect fans, be it CPU or case fans. In this situation make sure that you have installed the latest version of Speedfan and BIOS.

Once you update, then check if SpeedFan supports your motherboard chip. After that, you need to go into BIOS settings to bypass the CPU fans.

In BIOS under the Power tab, you will see the setting for ACPI suspend type. Change it from S3 to S1 and save the changes as a custom default. Then press F10 to exit from BIOS. It should resolve the Speed fan not detecting fan problems.

Simply downloading SpeedFan and hitting the UP arrow will not increase your PC fan speed. For that, you have to configure your PC.

Just click on the Configuration button and then on the Advance tab.
Now select your motherboard chip from the drop-down menu.
Here you should be able to see PWM 1 mode, PWM 2 mode, and PWM 3 mode.
Click on any one of them and set it to Software controlled.
Tick the 'remember it' box and hit OK.
Now if you click on the up or down arrow button, your PC fan speed will change accordingly.

download your motherboard specific software from [this website](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B450M%20Pro4-F/#Download)

and heres your motherboard [details](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B450M%20Pro4-F/)

apparently it uses a `AMD Promontory B450` chipset.

Hope it helps! if not just comment and I'll keep trying for other fixes.

Comment: Hey I did went on the Advanced setting and selected my Chip after I select my Chip I did found the option PVM 1 - 5 mode but when I click on the first mode basically all of them says the same its has Manual, some other options I did not found any option called "Software Control" for all the modes however I just kept all of them to manual. But the problem is as the other guy suggested I don't think that software have the ChipSet of my MotherBoard I use so I actually going to request them to add that.

Comment: great move. you can check out this [website](https://www.pcerror-fix.com/pc-fan-controller-software) to find out other software available.